# Paho MQTT 'Unsupported callback API version' error

Tags: python, mqtt, paho, hivemq

I am trying to implement Paho Python MQTT and connect to an online broker but the code seems to through an error.

```
ValueError: Unsupported callback API version: version 2.0 added a callback_api_version, see migrations.md for details
```

I was trying to implement a simple paho client example from the [given website](https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/how-to-use-mqtt-in-python); the following will reproduce the issue:

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client
import random

broker = 'broker.emqx.io'
port = 1883
topic = "python/mqtt"
client_id = f'python-mqtt-{random.randint(0, 1000)}'
client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
```

Comment: Provide the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I believe this will be  very common problem over the next couple of months (until old tutorials are updated). As such I've added a MRE from the article OP referenced.

Comment: @JustinBertram
You can find the code in the following link. Go to the 'The Code for Publishing MQTT Messages' section. Pasting the entire code here is going out of the character limit.

https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/how-to-use-mqtt-in-python

Comment: @Brits Thanks for the response. I made the required changes.

Answer (score 9):

[Release 2.0.0](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/releases/tag/v2.0.0) of the Paho Python MQTT includes breaking changes; this means that code written for v1.x will not work without some (minimal) modifications. As [v2.0.0](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/releases/tag/v2.0.0) was only released a few days ago (11th Feb 2024) most examples, including the one you reference, will **not** work.

The changes required are documented [here](https://eclipse.dev/paho/files/paho.mqtt.python/html/migrations.html) (or [here](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/docs/migrations.rst)); in your case it's likely that the only change needed is add a single parameter changing:

```
client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
```

to:

```
client = mqtt_client.Client(mqtt_client.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION1, client_id)
```

This will configure the library to use the v1 callback API (as used with older versions of the library). I would recommend reading the document linked above and planning to migrate to `CallbackAPIVersion.API_VERSION2`.

An alternative option would be to install a v1 release (v1.6.1 is the latest; `pip install "paho-mqtt<2.0.0"` will install this). V2 does include quite a few fixes/enhancements so it is worth considering using that version.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response!

After making the required changes, I am no more getting the error but I am finding it difficult to comprehend the output. My out is 'Failed to send message to topic test' but I am not sure what might be causing this error. Following the example for publishing mqtt messages on this link (https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/how-to-use-mqtt-in-python), I am unable to understand why is it failing to send the messages to the topic 'test'. The on_connect function is not giving any output whether it connected to the broker or failed to connect. How can I share the code?

Comment: Sorry - you need to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [not rely on links to external sites](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (there is plenty of space to copy the code that is failing into the question). With the change above, the code from the EMQX site runs fine for me (tested this before posting an answer) so pointing to the article is not really helpful. Note that as I've answered the initial question it's best to raise further issues in a new question (this one is now a reference for other users encountering the same issue).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is of any help to anybody running into the same problem. All credits go to Brits! With his feedback I managed to fix the issue for me. I could not get the client_id fix to work so I went with the following.
(EDIT: not direct answer to the original question but related to it)

The mqtt-gpio indeed installed paho-mqtt-2.0.0 (blue box). `pip install paho<2.0.0` didn't work for me as you can see below.
[image: Paho-Mqtt-2.0.0 not working]

I had to use `pip install "paho<2.0.0"` for it to work. It uninstalled Paho-2.0.0 and installs Paho1.6.1. May be for many people this is common sense but probably not for everybody. It wasn't for me as well (beginner over here!).
[image: Solution for me]

Hope this is of any help for someone.

Comment: Note that this is really an answer to a different, but related, question. It might be worth starting with "This issue can also arise when a library you import depends upon paho-mqtt, such as ..." and go from there (because others will hit this).

Comment: Please do not post images of code/text. Post the actual text and format it as code in the toolbar (images are hard to read, impossible for users of screen readers and unsearchable)

Answer (score 0):

Try this , if you don't want to upgrade to new version:

#Old
mqttc = mqtt.Client(client_id)

#New

mqttc = mqtt.Client(mqtt.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION1,client_id)

ref: https://eclipse.dev/paho/files/paho.mqtt.python/html/migrations.html

Comment: You would do this after upgrading to the new version of the library, in order to continue using the old version of the API. If you don't want to upgrade to the v2 library you would use `pip install "paho-mqtt<2.0.0"` (forcing PIP to install the latest V1 release).