# Upgrading PAHO MQTT to v2, where to add callback method?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to update some code someone else wrote that I've been providing a docker file for, as well as trying to keep up-to-date,since they no longer support it.  In the paho docs, for v2, you need to add "mqtt.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION1"  as  per [this page](https://eclipse.dev/paho/files/paho.mqtt.python/html/migrations.html).

In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77984857/paho-mqtt-unsupported-callback-api-version-error), I kind of had an idea, but I'm not a python expert and not sure exactly where to add the callback method.

The code I'm trying to update that calls the pahoo.mqtt.client is

```
#===========================================================================
#
# Broker connection
#
#===========================================================================
from . import config
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

#===========================================================================
class Client( mqtt.Client ):
   """Logging client
   """
   def __init__( self, log=None ):
      mqtt.Client.__init__(mqtt.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION1, self )
      self._logger = log
      # Restore callbacks overwritten by stupid mqtt library
      self.on_log = Client.on_log
      
   def on_log( self, userData, level, buf ):
      if self._logger:
         self._logger.log( level, buf )

#===========================================================================
def connect( configDir, log, client=None ):
   cfg = config.parse( configDir )

   if client is None:
      client = Client( log )

   if cfg.user:
      client.username_pw_set( cfg.user, cfg.password )

   if cfg.ca_certs:
      client.tls_set( cfg.ca_certs, cfg.certFile, cfg.keyFile )

   log.info( "Connecting to broker at %s:%d" % ( cfg.host, cfg.port ) )
   client.connect( cfg.host, cfg.port, cfg.keepAlive )

   return client

#===========================================================================
```

Am I correct in thinking that to make this work with client v2, i need to do this?

```
class Client( mqtt.Client ):
   """Logging client
   """
   def __init__( self, log=None ):
      mqtt.Client.__init__(mqtt.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION1, self )
      self._logger = log
      # Restore callbacks overwritten by stupid mqtt library
      self.on_log = Client.on_log
      
   def on_log( self, userData, level, buf ):
      if self._logger:
         self._logger.log( level, buf )
```

I tried asking chatgpt but got the following unhelpful code:

```
class Client(mqtt.Client):
    """Logging client"""
    def __init__(self, log=None):
        super().__init__(protocol=mqtt.MQTTv31, transport="tcp", clean_session=True, userdata=None,
                         protocol_version=mqtt.PROTOCOL_V31, callback=None)
        self._logger = log

    def on_log(self, userData, level, buf):
        if self._logger:
            self._logger.log(level, buf)
```

I also asked it to "rewrite it using version 2 of the library", and it came up with this:

```
class Client(mqtt.Client):
    """Logging client"""
    def __init__(self, log=None):
        super().__init__(protocol=mqtt.MQTTv5)  # Specify MQTT version 5
        self._logger = log

    def on_log(self, userdata, level, buf):
        if self._logger:
            self._logger.log(level, buf)
```

which might be correct, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry - your question is a bit confusing because your "code I'm trying to update" is identical to the "i need to do this?" code. The only change you should need is `mqtt.Client.__init__(self , mqtt.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION1)` (fixed order) but you also have the option of upgrading to the V2 api. Please remove the Chat GPT stuff (it only confuses things).