# MQTT on Raspberry Pi 3B+ (Raspbian) not working anymore

Tags: python, mqtt, raspberry-pi3, high-availability

Good day,

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (USB, No SD card) with a MQTT broker to control the GPIO of that Raspberry by input from Home Assistant. It has been working great for multiple years except for the fact that when I make a change or cut off the power, I need to reinstall the whole Raspberry Pi. Yesterday I change the setup to wired connection instead of wireless connection which made 3 of the 5 raspberry pi's corrupt again and required a reinstall.

I have completed the installation (according to this [link](https://github.com/flyte/mqtt-io)) many many times successfully but now I can't get it to work anymore. The supervisor is giving a problem but I can't figure out how to fix it:

```
pi@raspberrypi005:~ $ sudo supervisorctl update
pi_mqtt_gpio: added process group
pi@raspberrypi005:~ $ sudo supervisorctl status
pi_mqtt_gpio                     STARTING
pi@raspberrypi005:~ $ sudo supervisorctl status
pi_mqtt_gpio                     STARTING
pi@raspberrypi005:~ $ sudo tail /var/log/pi-mqtt-gpio.log
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/pi/ve/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pi_mqtt_gpio/server.py", line 12
69, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/home/pi/ve/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pi_mqtt_gpio/server.py", line 10
64, in main
    client = init_mqtt(config["mqtt"], config["digital_outputs"], config["stream
_writes"])
  File "/home/pi/ve/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pi_mqtt_gpio/server.py", line 41
0, in init_mqtt
    client = mqtt.Client(client_id=client_id, clean_session=False, protocol=prot
ocal)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback_api_vers
ion'
pi@raspberrypi005:~ $
```

The things I've already tried:

- Older version of Raspbian; Raspberry Pi Imager has been updatet.
- Different versions of Raspbian (32 Bit/64 bit)
- Different versions of Python; 3.7.3 was installed before but gives the same error at the moment. Used Pyenv to try another version but also gave the same error.
- Since two other raspberry pi's are still working, the problem is not within Home Assistant. No changes made there.

I think I tried 12 different times but I just ran out of ideas.

If there is any other information required, please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paho MQTT 'Unsupported callback API version' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77984857/paho-mqtt-unsupported-callback-api-version-error). Basically you have installed v2 of the paho library and this requires some changes to your code. Either install v1 (`pip install paho-mqtt<2.0.0`) or make [the required changes](https://eclipse.dev/paho/files/paho.mqtt.python/html/migrations.html).

Comment: Note that there is already [an issue](https://github.com/flyte/mqtt-io/issues/348) on the repo you linked.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Isn't this a different package than Paho? I did see the topic you refer to and I tried fixing it that way but i couldn't get it to work properly. I did not try to install the paho-mqtt<2.0.0 since I thought I was not using paho. And going trough the paho examples, it's quite a bit different.

Comment: Correct, however it imports and uses paho. As it does not limit the paho version you will get the latest (which contains breaking changes). The issue I linked suggests limiting the import to <v2 (you would need to do this manually until the repo is updated)

Comment: I will gives this a try since I couldn't get the other fix to work. I will let you know if this worked in a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Brits, It worked perfectly. I did had to use `pip install "paho-mqtt<2.0.0"` instead of `pip install paho-mqtt<2.0.0`. I will post screenshot in a new reply for other people who might run into the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer on the other question (the emqx team also suggested this but i had forgotten to make the change). Adding a comment on the guthub issue may also help some people.